# How to see report results by report suite in Omniture (SiteCatalyst)

Tags: report, adobe-analytics

I want to check reports generated by my site by report suite. So for the report suite I made in the SiteCatalyst, I want to check the reports generated.

Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you log into SiteCatalyst, all the reports you are populating are on the left hand menu. The report suite selector is the drop down box in the top middle of the screen. If you set any props, find those organized by number under the "custom traffic" menu and any evars are found in the "custom conversion" menu. I would highly recommend taking a look at the orientation videos found in the help section. They will help you get acclimated to the interface.

[image]